Trying to convert a PDF to a JPEG but I keep facing an error
I'm trying to convert a PDF into a JPEG using python. I'm trying to perform OCR by converting the PDF's into JPEG but keep running into the error:

cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7cf34c6276a0>

I've tried all sorts of stuff but just cants seem to bypass this error.
def convert_pdf_to_jpeg(self, jpeg_output_dir='jpeg_output'):
      try:
        
          os.makedirs(jpeg_output_dir, exist_ok=True)
          pages = convert_from_path(self.input_path, fmt='jpeg', poppler_path = '/usr/bin')
          image_paths=[]

          for i, page in enumerate(pages):
            image_path = os.path.join(jpeg_output_dir, f'page_{i+1}.jpg')
            page.save(image_path,'JPEG', quality=self.image_quality)
            image_paths.append(image_path)
            logging.info(f'Page {i+1} saved as JPEG at {image_path} with quality {self.image_quality}')

          return image_paths
      except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'PDF to JPEG conversion failed: {e}')
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise

and the way I indicate the path is:
pages = convert_from_path('/content/3031358-TTI_SN20210823-004(01SEP).pdf', dpi = 200, poppler_path='/usr/bin')


Extracting text indirectly (converting first to jpg) is quite an undertaking and can be full of side-effects. There are plenty of utilities that extract text from the original PDF. pdftotext and others come to mind. Of course they may also fail. Did you try that?

This error is usually caused by the pdf2image library not being able to read or parse the image of a certain page correctly when converting the PDF to an image.As you convert each page, you can catch the exception and skip the page that failed to convert:
for i, page in enumerate(pages):
try:
    image_path = os.path.join(jpeg_output_dir, f'page_{i+1}.jpg')
    page.save(image_path, 'JPEG', quality=self.image_quality)
    image_paths.append(image_path)
    logging.info(f'Page {i+1} saved as JPEG at {image_path} with quality {self.image_quality}')
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f'Failed to save page {i+1} as JPEG: {e}')


Extracting text indirectly (converting first to jpg) is quite an undertaking and can be full of side-effects. There are plenty of utilities that extract text from the original PDF. pdftotext and others come to mind. Of course they may also fail. Did you try that?

I did. My first work through was me using pdfplumber to convert the pdf to text and then extracting specific information with Regex. But some of the data end up being inaccurate. So, I thought perhaps converting it into an image would make it better. @jcoppens.

"But some of the data end up being inaccurate." Is there someething predictable in the errors you notice? The worst luck you can have is when the PDF recodes the text and uses a font encoded in the same PDF. Only a few pdf-to-text converters are capable to handle those - try several! (Calibre, poppler-utils, pdftotext, qpdfviewer, ...)
